# Select Rows where Day number is less than Given Threshold

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a timestamp column. Say I want to get the rows where the day number in the year is < 50

Where *Jan 1 = 1* and *Dec 31 = 366*

So the function is not year specific, I want to get the results between a day range e.g. 50 and 100 for all years.

**Example**

Timestamp

1. 2012-02-01
2. 2011-02-01
3. 2012-04-01

So retrieving those results where DAY < 50 would return results: 1 and 2 but NOT 3.

Comment: Use [DAYOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM TableA 
  WHERE  DAYOFYEAR(DateCol) < 50 -- for < 50



SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE  DAYOFYEAR(DateCol) between 50 and 100 --between a day range e.g. 50 and 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DAYOFYEAR()` function against the timestamp column in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(timestamp_col) < 50
```

Since day 50 occurs before February 29, there won't be any leap year considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS(yourdate) - TO_DAYS(CONCAT(YEAR(yourdate), '-01-01'))  + 1
```

Comment: Er... no. See @rs's answer instead. I was not aware of the `DAYOFYEAR` function.